# Adding up objects within a key within an nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a nsmutablearray called temparray. That nsmutablearray has a key called "mountains". The objects inside the key mountains are 14, 12, 16, 20, 20, 20. How do I add up the objects inside the key "mountains" only for objects equal to a string like @"20"?

Update 2: Due to popular demand, I have printed out the nsmutablearray using nslog. It will show you exactly what I have described all along.

```
2014-03-16 21:36:16.493 Labresults[7213:60b] temparray (
        {
        mountains = "20";
        cookies = "11";
        picturid = "4";
    }
        {
        mountains = "20";
        cookies = "2";
        picturid = "6";
    }
        {
        mountains = "32";
        cookies = "2";
        picturid = "9";
    }
)
```

Update: Here is what I have so far. It works, but I have to make it far simpler and quicker for it to work faster than a minute.

```
    -(void)mountainloop {
        if (fillerstring == NULL) {
            int x = 0;
            _first = NULL;
            _second = NULL;

            NSDictionary *itemAtIndex =(NSDictionary *)[temparray objectAtIndex:x];
            _first = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"mountains"];
            if ([_first isEqualToString:@"20"]) {
            float a = [_first floatValue];
            k = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: a];
}     
            x = x + 2;//make +2
            if (([temparray count] < x)) {
                _allmonthdail.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", _allmonthdail.text, a];
                temparray = NULL;         
            }
            else {
                x = x - 1;
                e = &x ;
                fillerstring = @"noo";       
                [self mountainloop];
            } 

        }
        else {
            int x= *(e);
            _first = NULL;

            NSDictionary *itemAtIndex =(NSDictionary *)[temparray objectAtIndex:x];
            _first = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"mountains"];
            if ([_first isEqualToString:@"20"]) {

            float a = [_first floatValue];
            float myfloatvalue = [k  floatValue];
            k = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: a + myfloatvalue];  
}       
            x = x + 2;
            if (([temparray count] < x)) {           
                float u = [k floatValue];
                _allmonthdail.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", _allmonthdail.text, u];
                temparray = NULL;         
            }
            else {
                x = x - 1;
                e = &x ;
                fillerstring = @"noo";               
                [self mountainloop];
            }}      
    }
```

Comment: It's not appropriate to delete a bad question and post a new bad question. Instead, you should update the question so it makes sense and is clear to everyone else. This question is as confusing as your previous one.

Comment: What are you talking about? I just signed up literally 20 minutes ago. Check out my profile if you don't believe me.

Comment: Sorry if I'm mistaken but this question is remarkably similar to another question that was asked just a short time ago and has now been removed.

Comment: Ignoring that, my comment still stands. This question is quite unclear. Show some relevant code. Show what you have tried so far to solve this. Explain what issue you are having.

Comment: @rmaddy Also, I have broken down it down as simple as I can. An nsmutable array has keys. Inside those keys are objects/data. Now read my question.

Comment: Adding some code. Alright. I will. Great suggestion. Still new to this.

Comment: Arrays don't have keys. Please post an example of your data structure.

Comment: I have just posted code that demonstrates this. Please take a look. I need something much quicker and simpler. @rmaddy

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes they do. Have you ever heard of [itematindex objectForKey:@"mountains"];? Take a look at my updated question to view an example.

Comment: `objectForKey:` is a method on `NSDictionary`, not `NSArray`.

Comment: No they do not -- arrays can have dictionaries as their individual elements, and those dictionaries can have keys, but arrays don't have keys. This is why we're asking you to post a print out of your array, so we can understand what you have.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you can also use objectForKey in a nsmutablearray, not a nsarray. They are two separate things in Xcode.

Comment: No, you can't. You can use `valueForKey:`, but it doesn't do the same thing as `objectForKey:` does for a dictionary.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Can you help me out with my question? I have an example listed above, but I need to greatly simplify and shorten it.

Comment: Any of us could help you if you would just post a print out of your array (or a portion of it) as both Josh and I have asked.

Comment: Alright, I will do that. Please wait a minute while I build and run.

Comment: @rdelmar I have printed out my array and updated the question with it. Does this help?

Comment: You were right, @rmaddy; this _is_ a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444269/calculating-the-sum-from-an-nsmutablearray-where-an-object-at-key-is-equal-to-a/

Comment: Just some of those values, ones that match a string like if I said @"20".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSIndexSet *indxs = [temparray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [obj[@"mountain"] isEqualToString:@"20"];
    }];

NSInteger sum = 20 * indxs.count;
```